# Sprite not following body / fixture

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Im trying to make sprites Stay on top of there static bodies (actually its fixtures) when the camera / screen moves. What do I need to do to achieve this?

`Background`: 
I have a player (which is dynamic, polygonshape, set as a box), which the camera follows as the player moves upwards in the screen.

Every X amount of meters i generate a (static) rectangle a few meters in front of the player. This Rectangle is the body im trying to draw a sprite on top of, the problem is when i draw it, the sprite stays static on the screen and doesnt stay ontop of the body/fixtures.

My Game screen follows my player like so:

```
box2dCamera.position.y = player.getPosition().y + box2dCamera.viewportHeight / 2 - (player.bodyHeight);
box2dCamera.update();
```

Im using libgdx-utils lib to draw the sprite ontop of the rectangle as follows:

```
Box2DSprite box2DSprite = new Box2DSprite(KidsGame.res.getTexture("badlogic"));
fixture.setUserData(box2DSprite);

sb.begin();
Box2DSprite.draw(sb, world);
sb.end();
```

thanks for any help

Comment: You need to set the `SpriteBatch`s `projectionMatrix` to `box2dCamera.combined`, so that it uses the `box2dCamera` to render things. If you don't do this, it uses some "default-projectionmatrix", which ofc, does not change/move with your `camera` and therefore the `Sprite` will stay at the same position on screen.

Comment: I already did that in my resize method like so `        box2dSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(box2dCamera.combined);`

Comment: You should do that in the render method, the `camera.combined` does change with every move of your character and therefore also the `SpriteBatch`s `projectionMatrix` needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SpriteBatch` uses a `Matrix4` for its rendering.
This `Matrix4` should be set to the `camera`s `combined` Matrix.
As the `camera.combined` is changed, when the `camera` moves, you should also update the `SpriteBatch`s `projectionMatrix` by calling `SpriteBatch#setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` inside the `render(delta)`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually need to draw fonts on top of the body, not sprites, which im still having issues with, i reposted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258453/draw-font-on-top-of-box2d-body