# Draw font on top of box2d body

Tags: libgdx, box2d

How can I draw text (font) on top of my static box2d body?

Background: Im able to draw sprites on top of bodies correctly. 
I do this by having a `box2dSpriteBatch` which is projected on box2dCamera like so `box2dSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(box2dCamera.combined);` And then simply rendering the sprite in the correct spot using `getPosition` of the body.

But if i try the same way for fonts, unfortunately it scales incredibly large, and if i try to scale the font down it doesn't appear. So im assuming I need to draw the text in window coordinates instead of box2d.

My attempt:

- in show(): 
  `windowCamera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`
- in my Render method i call 
  `windowSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(windowCamera.combined);`
- also in Render i render the font

  `whiteFont.setScale(0.7f, 0.7f);
  sb.begin();
  whiteFont.draw(sb, "2", body.getPosition().x, (questionLineBody.getPosition().y)*PPM);
  sb.end();`

Comment: @Springrbua maybe you can help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to Basically * my x position by PPM.

ie.

Add these lines to the Render method:

```
windowCamera.position.y = box2dCamera.position.y * PPM;
windowCamera.update();
windowSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(windowCamera.combined);
```

And Render the font like so:

```
whiteFont.draw (sb,"2", body.getPosition().x * PPM, body.getPosition().y * PPM);
```

Comment: Use a viewport and lose all the PPM.